# How to extract column then make a sum and sort it?

Tags: sorting, sed, awk, cut

I have problem extracting columns because not every column has a row.

Look at the picture:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1F/Fw/1dAklQ4M/snap008.jpg

Now I want to list column for example:

```
    "Label"   #2     #6    #sum of #2 and #6
```

I want to sort by last column and it is #sum of #2 and #6

How can I do that?
Thx

Comment: Post some test input and desired output. And [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Your problem could be specified better if all of the
additional/clarifying information from your comments were added to
your original post. Also make sure to mention all constraints so that
you can get some effective help. Not everyone reads all of the
comments. Thor is right, provide some usable
sample input (how am I going to test a solution against a .jpg image)
and some clear desired output).

Comment: The fact you're adding conditions to solve the problem as comments to every answer means: a.) your question is poorly specified, b.) you haven't explored the whole situation to know exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Using Gawk, you can use fixed-width columns to read your data:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 13 16 9 11 11 7 6 6 6 6 10 6 6 6 10 10" '{
  print $2, $9, $13, $9 + $13
}'
```

Please note that only guessed the columns widths from the screenshot. The widths will need to be adjusted.

You can also probably merge the column width for the columns you want to ignore.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size

Comment: `FIELDWIDTHS` (not `FILEDWIDTHS`) is a list of column width. For example, with `FIELDWIDTHS="9 13 16"`, `gawk` will use the first 9th characters for column 1 (`$1`), the next 13 characters for column 2, and the next 16 characters for column 3.

Comment: Ufff..This is not what I want..
I forgot to say that my table is dynamic and it changed evry time, so your solution is not acceptable for me..
Thx for help but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

A general answer, provided your input has "standard" awk/sort field delimeters, could be something like.

```
awk '{print $0, $2+$3}' | sort -n -k3
```

Depending on your input you might have to tinker with either the input or the pipeline of commands some.

Comment: But the problem is that generaly used awk won't to job as I want.
Thats because not every coloumn is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach if you know the number of columns you may have for valid input:

```
  awk 'NF > 5 {print $0, $2+$3 }' | sort -k3 -n
```

this will only process lines with at least 5 columns. Or if there was a range you could something like

```
  awk 'NF > 5 && NF < 9 { ... }'  | sort ...
```

`NF` is a predefined AWK variable that denotes the number of fields on the current line (ie columns of data for your purposes). The examples above filter out lines that do not meet the condition (so you can think of them as short versions of if-statements)

You'll have to adjust this to your needs since there's no usable test data.

Comment: Thx..but it pass some coloumn that I do not need it..
Thx anyway for help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming: 1. The numbers starting at #1 are always present. 2. No number is listed in any prior column. 3. That the first and second fields are never empty.

You could look for the first digit and start from there:

```
awk '{

# Look for the first digit
for( I=1 ; I<=NF ; I++ ) { if ( $I ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ ) { break } }

# Print the necessary fields
print $2, $(I+1), $(I+5), $(I)+$(I+5)

}' my_file
```